# Yandex Maps API - InteractivityModel для шаблона метки, чтобы вместо перетаскивания карты срабатывал drag внутри шаблона метки

Tags: jquery, yandex-maps-api, yandex-maps-jsapi

Есть метка, внутри ее шаблона есть интерактивный элемент - jquery-слайдер c событием drag, который я инициализирую по клику на метку. При стандартном InteractivityModel ('default#geoObject') при попытке тащить слайдер перетаскивается вся карта. С другими стандартными моделями либо без изменений, либо не перетаскивается ничего. Как заставить слайдер функционировать?

В клубе яндекса видела, что можно делать кастомную модель подобным образом:

```
var model = ymaps.util.extend(
    {}, ymaps.interactivityModel.map, {
        mousedown: {
            listenDomEvent: true,
            generateMapEvent: false,
            allowMapEvent: false
        }
    }
);
```

Мне это не помогло со слайдером, но и документацию по этим опциям я не нашла. Может возможно как-то еще добиться работы слайдера?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Все объекты на карте лежат под слоем событий (pane: 'events'), чтобы элемент ловил дом-события напрямую, надо поместить его поверх eventPane

```
iconPane: 'overlaps'
```

https://jsfiddle.net/ktwbfhys/6/

Полный список слоев [тут](https://tech.yandex.ru/maps/doc/jsapi/2.1/ref/reference/map.pane.Manager-docpage/).